# Slow show/hide sidebar menu and image in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a script that show/hide sidebar menu and image in modal, all function quick appearance, but i need it slow... i can't find decision... can you help please...

```
<script>
    function wbsn_open() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
}

function wbsn_close() {
document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}

// Modal Image Gallery
 function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `CSS-Transitions` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: can you show from where are wbsn_open and wbsn_close getting called ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you would do like this:

1. Add a class when the sidebar appear say for e.g. `sidebar-in` and that class add animation effect using css
2. Remove `sidebar-in` class and then add `sidebar-out` class this class will do the opposite animation

Something similar you can do for image gallery

#### Answer:

```
<script>
    function wbsn_open() {           
        var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
        document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
        sidebar.style.display = "block";
        sidebar.classList.remove("sidebar-out");
        sidebar.classList.add("sidebar-in"); // Magic happens here
    }

    function wbsn_close() {
        var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
        document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
        sidebar.style.display = "none";
        sidebar.classList.remove("sidebar-in"); 
        sidebar.classList.add("sidebar-out"); // Magic happens here
    }

    // Modal Image Gallery
    function onClick(element) {
        document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
        var gallery = document.getElementById("modal01"); 
        gallery.style.display = "block";
        gallery.classList.add("gallery-in"); // Magic happens here
    
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
    }
```

You can look css animation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

I highly suggest, use library like [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) it makes your life easier.

Create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so it's easy to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple tutorial from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein)

You could use jquery animate that allows you to control speed of event slow , fast & custom

```
 function wbsn_open() {
    $("#mySidebar").fadeIn(2000); 
    $("#myOverlay").fadeIn(2000); 
}
```

basically means..call the fadeIn i.e. display block  event after 300 nanoseconds.. & then call the callback function once all is done

```js
 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut(1300)
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeIn(1300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

<p style="color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
```

Comment: @COOOOOOL... but i need a modify my script.. sorry.. hope you understand..

Comment: try **$("#mySidebar").fadeIn(2000);** CHECK MY UPDATED ANSWER...you will get some idea

Comment: It's come in and quickly come out, than fading :(

Comment: did...you fadein fadeout all the .display = "none"; and .display = "block"; events...let me re write my answer one more time and let me know the result

Comment: function wbsn_close() {
    $("#mySidebar").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#myOverlay").fadeOut(2000);
}

Comment: also in onClick function there is $("#modal01").fadeIn(2000);

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees  it's perfect... You are the best. Thank you.